# Unity Linux How to change the built in IDE monodevelop with another IDE

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have installed the new experimental build of unity for Linux (Unity 5.1.0f3 ) and it's working great , but I faced some problems with the built-in IDE , It's [monodevelop 4.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8T84.png) , so I had used the [normal way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AwAN.png) to change it from unity to sublime text or the monodevelop 5.10 version , but it didn't work , scripts doesn't open with any of them , just the built-in IDE

- I use elementary os frya

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites, either  http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://askubuntu.com  . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Comment: ok I'll , thanks for your tip

Comment: @shellter The question is about tools used primarily by programmers. Such questions are not off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem by linking the shell script of my application rather than linking the desktop entry file
.